# How do I set the serialization options for the geo values using the official 10gen C# driver?

Tags: c#, serialization, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Considering this class:

```
public class Location
{
    public Coordinates Geo { get; set; }

    public Location()
    {
        Geo = new Coordinates();
    }

    public class Coordinates
    {
        public decimal Lat { get; set; }
        public decimal Long { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I have a geospatial index on the collection set like `{ Geo: "2d" }`. Unfortunately the driver tries to store lat/lon coordinates as strings, instead of numbers and I get an error that says *Tue Mar 15 16:29:22 [conn8] insert database.locations exception 13026 geo values have to be numbers: { Lat: "50.0853779", Long: "19.931276700000012" } 1ms*. To alleviate this problem I setup a map like this:

```
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<Location.Coordinates>(cm =>
{
    cm.AutoMap();
    cm.MapProperty(c => c.Lat).SetRepresentation(BsonType.Double);
    cm.MapProperty(c => c.Long).SetRepresentation(BsonType.Double);
});
```

Notice that there is no `BsonType.Decimal` nor anything like that. In the effect, when trying to call `Save()` I get a `MongoDB.Bson.TruncationException`, which seems logical. What are my options?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According this [bug(fixed Jan 21 2011 05:46:23 AM UTC)](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-113?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3aall-tabpanel), in c# official driver was added ability 'AllowTruncation'. So you need download latest driver version and enjoy! Also instead of SetRepresentation you can use BsonRepresentationAttribute like this:

```
public class C {
  [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.Double, AllowTruncation=true)]
  public decimal D;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I know I can use attributes, I just chose not to, I don't want more dependencies in my domain model.

Comment: @Pawel: So AllowTruncation=true work in new version? Because i not tested actually, and i also want know it.

Comment: Yes, it does, I couldn't find it in `SetRepresentation()` (wonder why it wasn't put there...), instead it has to be set via `SetSerializationOptions(new RepresentationSerializationOptions(BsonType.Double, false, true))`. Or the attribute, of course. I don't want to loose precision, but looking at the maps I guess it's "good enough".