# mongodb data losing when run web service in c#

Tags: c#, linq, web-services, mongodb

I have an entitiy class as

```
public class City
{
    [BsonId]
    public string id { get; set; }
    public int value { get; set; }        
}
```

I created a web service and there is a webmethod as

```
[WebMethod]
    public List<City> linQuery()
    {
        MongoConn dao = new MongoConn();
        MongoServer mongo = dao.getConnection();
        List<City> list = new List<City>();

        string dbName = dao.dbName();
        var db = mongo.GetDatabase(dbName);

        Console.WriteLine(db);
        using (mongo.RequestStart(db))
        {
            var collection = db.GetCollection<City>("cityMap");
            IQueryable<City> cities = collection.AsQueryable().Where(c => c.value > 1200);
            foreach (City city in cities)
                list.Add(city);
            return list;
        }
    }
```

when I run the service, I get that error:

```
System.IO.FileFormatException: An error occurred while deserializing the value property of class WebService1.City: Truncation resulted in data loss. ---> MongoDB.Bson.TruncationException: Truncation resulted in data loss.
```

How can I solve this problem?
Thanks for your helps.

Comment: Change the field  public int value { get; set; } to  public double value { get; set; }

Comment: @ToanNguyen thanks for answer. I changed the type of attribute and service don't throw exception.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

did you try set `AllowTruncation=true` for your properities in `City` class?

```
public class City
{
    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.Int, AllowTruncation=true)]
    public string id { get; set; }
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.Int, AllowTruncation=true)]
    public int value { get; set; }        
}
```

[How do I set the serialization options for the geo values using the official 10gen C# driver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5314238/how-do-i-set-the-serialization-options-for-the-geo-values-using-the-official-10g)

Answer (score 10):

You typically don't want your model to know or care how it's being stored, so peppering it with `MongoDB.Bson` attributes is not ideal. You can configure how MongoDB.Driver should read and store decimals with this config instead.

```
BsonSerializer.RegisterSerializer(
  typeof(decimal),
   new DecimalSerializer(BsonType.Double,
   new RepresentationConverter(
     true, // allow overflow, return decimal.MinValue or decimal.MaxValue instead
     true //allow truncation
    ))
 );
```

[source](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/master/src/MongoDB.Bson/Serialization/Options/RepresentationConverter.cs)

Comment: It works, I used it to circumvent a faulty model who had used doubles instead of decimals, adding this to the processor allows it to continue without converting the old data, at least until we don't need the data anymore, this is a great fix for that

Comment: Where might such a piece of code be put?  It looks static, but it'd make sense to go in something like a Startup file, right?  Assuming it's a global thing for the lifetime of the app.

Comment: Alec yes it's global. I'd lean towards a static constructor in your repository because that keeps all your MongoDB stuff in one place, but if that class is generic I'd go with Startup.

Comment: You have the comments on the arguments the wrong way around. `allowOverflow` is the first, `allowTruncation` is the second. (Checked against MongoDB C# Driver 2.12)